# Core Data: Do we need to re-fetch after every delete?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, ios8, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi Please could someone help me?

I am using **core data** with **tableview controller**. I am using an **NSFetchedResultsController (NSFRC)** and **NSManagedObjectContext (NSMOC)**.

1) I am doing `NSFRC.performFetch` inside the view did load
2)  When the user deletes a row I am doing `NSMOC.deleteObject`

App crashes, complaining that the number of rows didn't decrease after the delete

Doing a `NSFRC.performFetch` just after the delete solves it. But I thought it should work without us having to force a  fetch? Please could someone explain this to me? I am using **IOS 8** (beta 5) with Swift by the way

Comment: Can you show us your implementations of
`tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and of the various NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods?

Comment: Did my solution work for you? In addition to the code I posted, you must declare that your view controller implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, as well, before the delegate methods are called on the deletes.

Comment: CoffeCoder, please mark the answer as correct. It is cautious to do so when someone helps you.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods to catch changes to get NSFetchedResultsController to be notified when the underlining data changes (e.g., deletes and adds).

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Also, declare that your view controller implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.